# Kotlin Toolbar Menu Icon issue

Tags: java, android, menu, kotlin

I converted the following Java Code to Kotlin Code. Android Studio does not show any error message.
But the result is different. I added two pictures of the emulator result.
As you can see the Java one works fine and shows the 3-dot menu icon in the toolbar. But the Kotlin code does not work.
Do someone know what the mistake is? Hope for some help. Thanks.

**Java:**

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

                //...
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);

                return view;
            }



        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuItem settings = menu.findItem(R.id.settings);
                MenuItem singOut = menu.findItem(R.id.sign_out);
                settings.setVisible(true);
                singOut.setVisible(false);
        }
```

[image]

**Kotlin:**

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        //...
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return view
    }



      override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, menuInflater: MenuInflater?) {
            menuInflater!!.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        }

        override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?) {
            val settings = menu!!.findItem(R.id.settings)
            val singOut = menu.findItem(R.id.sign_out)
            settings.isVisible = true
            singOut.isVisible = false
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
settings.isVisible = true
singOut.isVisible = false
```

to:

```
settings.visible = true
signOut.visible = true
```

Check this doc for explanation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

**Update**: actual code in question is right - `settings.isVisible` should work.

Comment: visible does not exists

Comment: My bad, your variant in question should work. It will call setVisbile(boolean) method.

You can always check java representation of your code by going to Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode  and press "Decompile" button

Comment: it should but it doesnt. Its strange maybe a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this?

```
settings.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
signout.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```